# How to use async function in style layers?

Tags: openlayers

I try to use a function `export const styleIconFeatureFunction = async () => {}` for style:

```
 const clusterVector = new VectorLayer({
    source: clusterSource,
    zIndex: zIndex ?? Infinity,
    style: (feature) =>
      styleIconFeatureFunction(
        feature,
        icon,
        {
          pointIcon,
          pathAttributesSelection,
        },
        this.baseHref
      ),
  });
```

This function has await inside. How to use it in style?

I have tried this:

```
 style: (feature) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        styleIconFeatureFunction(
          feature,
          icon,
          {
            pointIcon,
            pathAttributesSelection,
          },
          this.baseHref
        ).then((data) => resolve(data));
      });
    },
```

Comment: And what happens? Any errors in the browser debugger console? Result not as expected?

Comment: the style can not handle async just sync

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A style function must return a style synchronously.  You could use a cache of styles indexed by feature id (and any of the other parameters if they might change).  If the style is already available use it, otherwise resolve it asynchronously, store it in the cache and force a re-render of the layer when ready.

```
  const styleCache = {};

  const clusterVector = new VectorLayer({
    source: clusterSource,
    zIndex: zIndex ?? Infinity,
    style: (feature) => {
      const style = styleCache[getUid(feature)];
      if (!style) {
        styleIconFeatureFunction(
          feature,
          icon,
          {
            pointIcon,
            pathAttributesSelection,
          },
          this.baseHref
        ).then((style) => {
          styleCache[getUid(feature)] = style;
          clusterVector.changed();
        });
      }
      return style;
    },
  });
```